# Use multiple namespace in wash_out gem in ruby

Tags: ruby, soap, xsd, wash-out

I have following request to be created in my SOAP API and using this gem https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out/

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <OGHeader xmlns="http://example.com">
    </OGHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <BookingRequest xmlns="http://example.com/Booking.wsdl">
      <Reservation Action="CREATE">
        <UniqueIDList xmlns="http://example.com/Unique/">
          <UniqueID type="FAR" xmlns="www.uio.com/Common/">201801111429</UniqueID>
        </UniqueIDList>
      </Reservation>
    </BookingRequest >
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How to use wash_out to create such request with particular namespace defined in each xmlns?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I tried following code to generate xml using wsdl but i want namespaces in my generated xml:
:BookingRequest => {
                :Reservation => {
                         :@Action => :string,
                    :UniqueIDList => {
                        :UniqueID => {
                            :@type => :string,
                             :text => :integer
                        }
                    }
                }
            }